# Vba keep previous cell value or skip if vlookup returns N/A

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a large data set of countries and their cost of living index. They need to be updated quarterly by copying a table from a website.

I made a macro to vlookup the updated index and replace the old one, but some entries no longer exist in the updated one or are not included. It leaves the index cell with #N/A, but I rather just leave the old value.

```
'Varibles and format
Dim last As Integer
Dim Ending As Integer
Dim examin As Variant
Ending = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
last = Range("G3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Range("F3:F" & last).ClearContents
Range("I3:M" & last).ClearContents 

'Find & Replace country names with correct from
Cells.Replace What:="United States", Replacement:="USA", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="United Kingdom", Replacement:="England", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="United Arab Emirates", Replacement:="United_Arab_Emirates", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="Dominican Republic", Replacement:="Dominican_Republic", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="South Africa", Replacement:="South_Africa", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="Czech Republic", Replacement:="Czech_Republic", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="Costa Rica", Replacement:="Costa_Rica", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

'Vlookup updated index 
For x = 2 To Ending
Range("D" & x).Value = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & x), Range("G3:H" & last), 2, False)
Next x
End Sub
```

I read on this question "How to keep previous excel cell value if VLOOKUP return with error" that it was not an option, but there might be a different way.

Here is what it looks like after I run it.

[image: Index Update]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For x = 2 To Ending
  If isnumeric(Application.VLookup(Range("A" & x), Range("G3:H" & last), 2, False)) then
  Range("D" & x).Value = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & x), Range("G3:H" & last), 2, False)
  End if
  Next x
End Sub
```

Try that